# Low performance in the MC34063 chip. Wrong BJT voltages, out of spec timings - how not to trust a datasheet

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, pcb, analog, boost

**EDIT at the bottom.**

Referring to a [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595748/mc34063-inductor-current-peak-does-not-match-calculations) which I solved, it was related to a inverting boost configuration of the MC34063 with the following arrangement:

Picture 1
[image]

I realized my circuit and calculations were right, and the question was solved. What remained open, though, was another issue: why from the measurements the Vsat of the internal switch was 1.6V or so, while by following the components selection, it should still be in the range of less than 0.5V (from datasheet).

To recap the component selection:

- R1 = 0.33 Ohm
- C1 = 47μF (electrolytic)
- R2 = 49.5 kOhm
- R3 = 2.49 kOhm
- C3 = 680 pF
- D1 = V4PAN50-M3/I
- L1 = SRN1060-221M
- C6 = 47μF (electrolytic)

I had the correct 50mA at the minimum input voltage of 6.5V, obtainable from the following formula:

\$ \frac{t_{on}}{t_{off}} = \frac{|{V_o}| + V_{diode}}{V_{in}-V_{sat}} \$

Measuring the on/off time ratio at the worse case scenario of the minimum input voltage with the maximum load (50mA), I discover that the minimum input voltage is 6.5V, since the on/off time ratio is 5.2 and the Vsat is 1.6V. Putting values in the formula will actually verify what is happening.

My question is why the chip keeps an on/off time ratio close to the minimum in the datasheet with all the 6 parts I tried, and why the Vsat is so high (way out of spec).

This is the scope acquisition of the pin 3 on channel 1 (timing capacitor) and the pin 2 on channel 2:

Picture 2
[image]

And here on channel 2 and 4 are, respectively, the pin 2 and the pin 1  (shorted with 7 and 8), showing the input voltage at around 6.5V (on the acquisition is lower at 6.1V though...), and during on-time the inductor voltage is around 4.5V, see acquisition:

Picture 3
[image]

The acquisition is taken with a light load, as you can see the inductor current goes to zero and voltage oscillate at a certain resonant frequency before decaying to zero.

Is there anything obvious here?

**EDIT:**

- There was a complain about not having the original schematic that I have used, so here it is.
- Also, in an answer I've been pointed out that the max Vce sat is 1.3V, while I wan mentioning it was 0.5V. Indeed I was wrong, but is also important to mention that this still does not explain my reading of 1.6V which is above the absolute maximum.
- A scope acquisition was not convincing, so since I have no access to it now, I will update with a better one a bit later.

**EDIT 1:**

- Scope acquisition updated posted in this EDIT1:

Picture 4
[image]

The natural ringing of the oscillator now shows that there is no fundamental error in my setup/calibration.

**The open question, considering the observations I received of the Vce_sat, is the following:**

Why the V_ce stays around the maximum value from the datasheet (max 1.3V, measured 1.6V), far from the typical? And, from [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/595748/mc34063-inductor-current-peak-does-not-match-calculations), why the t_on/t_off ratio stays around the minimum value of 5.27, where minimum is 5.2? Is this related somehow? Did I missed something else?

I just wonder if someone else had a similar issue with similar specs. I am using a PCB I designed. As I have no problems in posting the grounding of the top of the test board I made (the bottom is just an entire GND plane), and also a 3D view, I hope I can provide some more insights now:

Also, the effectively mounted component, are the one shown in the initial schematic.

Picture 5
[image]
Picture 6
[image]

Comment: When you show a circuit diagram it trumps words. When you then use words to give new values of components already placed in that schematic, you do the reader a disservice. Use your favourite picture editor and update the circuit and throw away the words that attempt (rather poorly) to do the same. Simplify for the reader and put notes in the diagram about the load resistance. Be specific and don't ask people to guess.

Comment: Are you sure your scope is properly calibrated? Perhaps one of the channels has a bit of a voltage offset, making the calculated difference incorrect. Try connecting both channels to pin 1 and see if you get a zero difference.

Comment: Regarding the schematic, I really hope it will help more with the new update.
@TooTea I will put a more complete acquisition soon.

Comment: I can't make sense of the scope shots, which color is which pin?

Comment: @bobflux I edited with the specified channel associated to the relative pin - forgot that for the first picture!

Comment: OK! On the first scope shot, "pin 1 (shorted with 7 and 8) on channel 2" I see voltage drops a lot, and the input setting is 10V/div DC, but how can this be since pins 1-7-8 are supposed to be the input voltage, it should be quite stable...

Comment: Gosh, I reversed the description on the image, now is correct, apologies. There should not be other mistakes hopefully.

Comment: @thexeno is there still an unanswered aspect or is this issue solved?

Comment: @ChristianB. My apologies, was not able to analyze the answers as I did now. I am aware of the bounty expiration time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short verification simulation using LTSpice and the MC33063A model from http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Simulating_the_MC34063_in_Inverter_Configuration_with_an_Accurate_TL431A_Model yields the following behavior (one has to remove the I2 declaration below the "force f/f reset at startup" comment in the model):

[image: Simulation result of the MC34063 circuit.]
[image: Simulation result for shown circuit. Shown are the voltage before (green) and after (blue) the transistor.]
Simulation result for shown circuit. Shown are the voltage before (green) and after (blue) the transistor.

This is in a good agreement with the captured curves. A short inspection shows the current through R3 and the voltage drop between Pin 1,7,8 and 2 according to the simulation.
[image]

So what is going on? Well a short search yields that some datasheet actually show the following curve:

[image]

This looks like the observed behaviour. A closer look to the specs reveals that they actually "cheat" a bit: they show the CE of the separate stages. You have to add both to get the actual relevant total CE.

EDIT: to add on the \$\frac{t_{on}}{t_{off}}\$ question - as observed in the simulation \$I_{pk}\$ is around 330 mA for an one ohm voltage supply. Assuming an output load current \$I_o\$ of 25 mA one gets
$$I_{pk} = 2 I_o \cdot \left(\frac{t_{on}}{t_{off}}+ 1 \right) \\
 => \frac{I_{pk}}{2 I_o} - 1 =\frac{t_{on}}{t_{off}} = \frac{|V_o| + V_F}{V_{in} - V_{sat}} => |V_o| = \left(\frac{I_{pk}}{2 I_o} - 1 \right) \cdot (V_{in} - V_{sat}) - V_F \\ 
\approx \left(\frac{330 mA}{2 \cdot 25 mA} - 1 \right) \cdot (6.3 V - 1.5 V ) - 0.4 V \approx 27 V $$
This is already pretty close the target voltage. One will notice that most parameters like \$V_F\$ and \$V_{sat}\$ are actually depending on the current. Actually \$I_{pk}\$ goes down while approaching the theoretical maximum voltage limit and depends on the on time. For longer periods the current can ramp up more allowing for higher voltages or output currents. For details I recommend setting up the simulation.

EDIT2: The ratio \$\frac{t_{on}}{t_{off}}\$ is defined by ratio \$\frac{I_{dischg}}{I_{chg}}\$ if no inbetween reset is triggered e.g. if the target voltage is reached. So looking into the charge current of C2 we see:

[image]

Current over C2. First marker line at 43.5 µA, second marker at -206.9 µA.

Checking the datasheet, one notice that the charge current is "too high", resulting in a low ratio. A short look into the model reveals that the bias current of 35 µA is accompanied by a leakage current of ~ 10 µA over S3. If Roff is changed to e.g. 1e17 the ratio goes up and the circuit works as "expected". Same goes if the difference between VCC and the target voltage is reduced i.e. target voltage lowered.

[image]

TL;DR: everything seems to work fine and within specs/model. One just have to interpret them in the intended way and mind their finite limitations.

Comment: In this datasheet (https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc34063a-d.pdf) you show the Fig. 5. There is also Vce in Fig.6 - does that mean that my configurations has the conditions of Fig. 5? For the rest, is a great simulation, thanks for that.

Comment: Because interestingly, I measure a 1.6V of saturation, which happens, according to the graph, at a peak of 0.9A, although it does not reach it: the ton/toff impedes the inductor to charge at such current. With your formula you are showing that what happens makes sense according to ton/toff, and we are limited by this value that limits the peak current, therefore the output power (I and/or V). But the problem is that the logic won't allow a longer ton/toff, and this depends from the oscillator - this I cannot explain. How behaves your simulation with an input of 4.5V?

Comment: (Input voltage at output loads from 25mA to 50mA - if your model is like the real part, the ton/toff will not allow you to reach the full -25V @50mA, not even 25mA --> but according on the ratio in the datasheet, -IT SHOULD-) That is the mistery to me, the second half of the mistery, worth to say

Comment: I will simulate. It will proof you answer on the Vce, although cannot give explanations on the timing ratio not met. BUT, i might be that I did not achieved the  maximum ton/toff because of the reset issued from the drop on the 0.33 resistor. Meaning I have to check against the simulation if I was reaching peaks earlier (then why?). Not to mention tolerances on the comparator in the timing circuit. But the calculations  were showing was possible to achieve -25V, with peak current 0.9A (4.5V). Using worse case scenarios did not change so much as I see in reality.

Comment: @thexeno sorry - i did not have the time yet to look into this more closely yet. But I can give you a starting point to look into it yourself: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p834btnqdalu3uj/stackexchange.asc?dl=0 - this is the used circuit unifying the outer circuit with the inner MC34063 model. It seems like I might be mistaken regarding the Vce - simulation shows a drop of ~ 0.7V per stage. I will try to find a more solid explanation as soon as I find the time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is that the same internal model that I see in the http://ltwiki.org link you provided?

Comment: basically yes. Only with the already adjustment that I removed the I2 model.

Comment: small addition: reason why Vce drop is >1.4 V is that the base and the collector share the same voltage source which implies that 2 *Vbthreshold must be taken into acount. Below that threshold no significant current will flow.

Comment: I run the simulations. Basically things are behaving like in my real setup, with the same issues at 4.5V - reason is that the ton/toff ratio, in your simulation is similar to mine: jumps around 5.7, plus distortions due to the Vcc resistance.
Tweaking the model, with a smaller Ichg from 35uA to 24uA I get indeed higher t-on, up to ratio of 6 or 7, and delivering more power. 
Also, I verified that I am limited by the timing, and not by Ipk protection (changing Vth internally won't affect anything, and never switches to higher Ich to reset the timer).

Comment: *question is* why we do get same "wrong" results simulated and in real: are we reading the timing in the datasheet wrongly? this is also in discordance with all the MC34063 calculators around.

Comment: As you said, on the switches, and as pointed in other comments, we do get the the sum of the Vbe as a Vce because it is not in saturation, but sees the drop from the flip-flop driver, Q1 and Q2 Vbes. The <1.3V is related with the boost with the external transistor, which put Q1 (internal last BJT stage) in saturation -> which should be up to 1.3V. As I am using internal BJT, I never reach saturation. This should be taken into account when designing limits. Although, has nothing to do with timing erros, which still I ignore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132598/discussion-between-christian-b-and-thexeno).

Answer (score 8):

I honestly haven't studied your scope outputs. (I apologize for that, as I'm glad you added them, regardless.) But I did do a quick check for *obvious* thoughts. And I have one for you.

[This MC34063A datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mc34063a.pdf) shows the following:

[image]

You write:

> it should still be in the range of less than 0.5V (from datasheet).

Note the specifications when pins 1 and 8 are connected, as you show them in your schematic.

What are the specifications shown there?

Comment: And this is why we don't use BJTs for power electronics anymore.

Comment: This doesn't really say why the measured Vce is more than 1.6 V when the specs say 1.3 V max,  1 V typical. That's still a huge difference.

Comment: @TooTea Agreed! However, the OP make an incorrect statement. Also, the specification provides values that are much closer to observation. This still means there is a residual difference to explain. But the OP also asked for *"anything obvious here?" And I provided at least one step in the right direction, there.

Comment: Indeed I oversee this spec (actually, more forgotten...) but  as mentioned, I am still out of the maximum spec. Just wondering, before providing better acquisitions, is the way I measured the Vce sat correct?

Comment: @TooTea I edited the question with the new acquisitions and also the physical representation of my test circuit

Comment: Just to be sure I understand, the darlington configurations, is not when we also connect the collectors together? Because figure 5 and 6 of the datasheet (https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc34063a-d.pdf) mention only Emitter follower or Common emitter configurations. To me seems I am in the Emitter follower configuration, as I am loading the inductor and not to ground. Because in many parts I see also the menton of "Darlington" and "non-darlington" configurations, this is bit confusing.

Comment: @thexeno *Figure 9a. External NPN Switch* is a Darllington configuration and it will have as much as 1.3 V between collector and emitter of the external BJT when actively ***on***. But also, any time you hook up pin 8 directly to pin 1, per Figure 11/11a, then the ***internal*** pair of BJTs are in Darlington.

Comment: @thexeno I'm not sure from your text and images, but is that a fair bit of MHz level damped ringing occurring on the combined pins, 1, 7, & 8?

Comment: I understand your first comment in terms of internal an external BJT, thank you. Then is clear that with the internal Darlington, I have to rely on graphs and not the 1.3V in the OUTPUT SWITCH table (table 7.6 of your answer). But in that table, they clearly state "pin 1, 8 connected", and is not the case in Figure 9a. Also, the 0.7V in the same table, is only the Vce between pins 1 and 2 (representing the first stage of the Darlington made with the external NPN)? In other words, as I understood the various answers, what they mean with the values in the table?

Comment: And yes, it might be at that MHz level. To me makes sense, because the inductor only sees parasitics on ground, diode and emitter, when current reaches zero- and I read is quite normal in this stage, unless we put some snubber or the like. Isn't the case?

Comment: (and I forgot the interaction with its own capacitance)

Comment: I still have this problems of the timing (see answer with the simulation) - I think since is the most impeding problem, any most substantial answer (if is possible to give any) should get the bounty that needs to be closed soon.

Comment: @thexeno I think that answer may be about where things are at. Doesn't it answer your issues in your mind?

Comment: Hi, the issues were why things seems out of spec, which were 2: one for the BJT (mostly solved), the second for the timing. If there is no apparent cause in something, I'm also ok in assuming there is a defect of any kind in my ICs, but I'd like a confirmation. I was fascinated by the concrete help got so far, anyway.

Comment: @thexeno Hmm. I just attempted to read more of that answer. The writer appears to suggest that the simulation model itself includes an S3 switch-off impedance that is "leaky." Assuming the model is a good representation of the internal switch, then the writer further suggests that this leakage explains the timing difference between the expected and actual results -- as the writer modified the model to remove the effect and the timing came out much closer to the predicted value. Is that your reading, too?

Comment: Yes is very much the same  I read - and tried. This answers to why the model is wrong - and that's ok. But the suspicion comes from the (original model), which I simulated and works almost identical to the real parts I have on my bench. No one changed the leakage of my ICs :) - Does this means all the MC34063 (not the MC33063) are inherently out of spec, and the model just tries to model them? I get reproducible behavior with all the (trusted origin) parts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132601/discussion-between-thexeno-and-jonk).

Comment: @thexeno I added some comments.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the Darlington connection for the device. Therefore the relevant spec is 1.3 V.

This spec is for the voltage between pins (1 and 8) and pin2. Your scope shot shows the V on VCC and pin 2; you are ignoring the I*R drop on the 0.3 Ω, and don't show the current.

Use the scope to display pins 1 and 2 simultaneously.

(Also - do you have genuine parts ?- from a reputable
distributor ?)

You are not measuring the saturation voltage of the driver -- you are measuring the V between pins 1 (&8) and 2. However this Darlington is driven from VCC (pin 6), and the voltage at pin 2 (switch emitter) is defined by the drop of the internal driver (say 0.3 VCE_sat of a PNP) plus the VBE of each NPN in the switch (say 0.7 V each) -- **for a total of 1.7 V.**

You 'gain' some saturation measurement by the 0.3 Ω -- basically this doesn't affect the voltage on pin 2 *until* the switch output transistors saturate (at ~ V(8,2) = 1.3 V). Basically you could *increase* R1 with no effect on V(6) until those transistors saturate.

Comment: Hi, in the third picture, "channel 2 and 4 are the pin 1 and the pin 2". the EDIT was basically showing the same acquisition, but showing also that the ringing was going back to zero - since this was addressed in a comment as a potential error in my scope. So I am measuring after the 0.3 Ohm. You can also notice the slope due to the current increase in the inductor.

Comment: The parts were from Mouser. I thought could be hand soldering, but the big issues I saw were only with high precision parts that loose some precision, i.e. calibrated gm in a current sense device showing different gain - although still in range.

Comment: FYI - I reverted a description in two acquisitions, now is corrected, my apologies. Although your answer remains relevant, irrespective to the correction.

Comment: fundamentally, you are not measuring VCE_SAT in this configuration since the voltage drop between pins 6 and 2,5 is VCE_SAT of an internal PNP plus 2 VBEs of the main switch. The voltage between 1,7,8 and 2,5 is just this above value minus the I*R drop across the 0.3 Ω. This is not the limiting VCE_SAT. You can only observe VCE_SAT with this IC using a boost configuration, or some more complex driver circuits.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the consideration! Technically I was taking into account the 0.3Ω as I was taking into account the slopes due to the drop on it. So you mean that the graph n.6 in this datasheet (https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc34063a-d.pdf) measures the Q1 Vce, while I was measuring according with the graph n5? Also What is not clear in you answer is: by limiting VCE_SAT, you mean the one of Q1?

Comment: Any thought on why I do see also a ton/toff time so off? this should depend on the internal logic/timing only

Comment: VCE_SAT is when the base current * beta exceeds the collector current (which would be externally limited). In the emitter-follower configuration you are using the switch with, this is not the case. You are measuring VCE, not VCE_SAT. This VCE is controlled by the VBE of the 2 transistors plus the VCE_SAT of the internal PNP driver.

Comment: It all makes sense on the voltage at least, now. In the Darlington configuration, out switch cannot saturate, as is also written. When is mentioned non-darlington, part of the boosted voltage is redirected to pin 1, to overdrive the external npn from the pin 1 (figure 9B in the ds). So we are talking about a universe of difference from my standard inverting implementation.

Comment: If that's correct, I wonder how they "cheated" on the timings as well. :)

Comment: I still have this problems of the timing (see answer with the simulation) - I think since is the most impeding problem, any most substantial answer (if is possible to give any) should get the bounty that needs to be closed soon.

Answer (score 3):

Tony Stewart provided the answer already: the Ic current controls the Vce value.
The Vce SAT is not a carve in stone value. It varies depending on the collector current controlled by the load (in your case the inductor current of 900mA).
What the Vce SAT in the specs means is that this is the value when for a very small change in the collector current there is a major change in the Vce voltage as opposed to below the Vce SAT when a major change in the collector current cause a minor change in the Vce voltage.
So, for a load current (inductor current) of 900mA the Vce is 1.6 volts as per Figure 4. Emitter Follower Configuration Output of the data sheet.
The following video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fqeUpATJlZY presents a technique that uses the Vce voltage specifically to control the current limit of a circuit (like an electronic circuit breaker). It provides several experimental results showing how the Vce changes as the collector current changes, for different base current.

Answer (score 1):

> Why the V_ce stays around the maximum value from the datasheet (max 1.3V, measured 1.6V), far from the typical?

I haven't looked closely, but in general this chip is often used in a rather pessimistic way. Connected as shown in the datasheet, with pin 1 and 8 connected together, the output Darlington does *not* operate in saturation, but rather as an emitter follower. We can do better!

To operate the output transistor in saturation - or close to, the input to the driver collector - at pin 8 - must be *higher* than the input voltage at pin 1. Sure, the output stage will turn off slower, but at high currents it won't be *that* much slower.

To get the output transistor to saturate, one has to generate a boosted voltage for the driver's collector. Like this, for example:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvSVgM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That way, Q1's output will be just VCEsat below the input voltage, and the efficiency of the thing will improve quite a bit under heavy load. For light loads, it doesn't matter.

The added components are: C1, C2, C3, D2, D3, D4, U1. The VCVS can be implemented in many ways - it can be fairly simple since we really mostly care about what happens when the threshold is crossed. So, something like the following would work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN86iO.png)</sup>

When Rs is drops around 0.3V, R4 will also drop around 0.3V, and the current limiting function of the chip will kick in. The resistor values in this circuit are a starting point, they can be adjusted in quite a few ways to get good performance across a range of temperatures.

Another way is to use Q2 collector current as a proxy for Q1's collector current:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftrdTx.png)</sup>

Tweaking things some more:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUZXRP.png)</sup>

The series voltage regulator has been replaced with shunt regulator, since we mostly want two diode drops to improve performance, so we may as well use two diodes.

Q3 can replace the Schottky diode D4 if you wanted to do that for some reason. The pairs of diodes connected in series - D5+D6, D7+D8 - can be replaced by an IR LED each.

C1 and R2 should be sized so that the shunt regulator doesn't drop out.

Answer (score -2):

[image]
https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc34063a-d.pdf

> Why (does) V_ce stay around the maximum value from the datasheet (max 1.3V, measured 1.6V), far from the typical?

Fundamental to all transistors as "switches" is that they have bulk resistance and hFE or Beta must be over-driven to 10% of the maximum linear value in order to reach the rated Vce=Vce(sat) @ Isat.

This is self-evident by the slope \$ R_{CE}=\dfrac{V_{CE_{(sat)}}}{I_C}\$of Figures 5 and 6 from the pdf file below it.

[image]

Using the left plot.

Thus looking at the current loop we can simplify it as follows;

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPTAkz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Ic current controls the Vce value, which you can measure with a 10:1 probe (tip & ring and no grd clip) on a 10 mohm shunt on 0V=Gnd with lead lengths < 1cm (10nH).

If your problem is transformer saturation measuring current only the way I descibed will reveal the problem. This may reduce parasitic issues with your measurement methods.